# Unable to hide and show text boxes after refresh the page

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to hide and show text boxes by radio button  using jquery. I can show and hide text boxes but the error is I have a drop-down list. When I select drop-down value the page getting refreshed. After page refresh I am unable to do hiding and showing of text boxes. I have update panel for ajax. Why I am unable to hide and show text boxes after page refresh? Here is my source code. Please help me.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ExperienceADD.aspx.cs" Inherits="Manjilas.WebForm31"%>
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"> 
<head>
 <script src="Scripts2/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts2/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts2/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('input[name="type"]').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Experienced') {
            $('#txtcomp').Show();
            $('#txtfrom').Show();
            $('#txtto').Show();

       } else {
       $('#txtcomp').hide();
            $('#txtcomp').hide();
            $('#txtfrom').hide();
            $('#txtto').hide();

        }
    });
   });
  </script>
  </head>    
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="well span5 center login-box">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                <b><font size="4">ADD EXPERIENCE DETAILS</font></b>
                </div>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                <div>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
                    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel2" runat="server"></asp:UpdatePanel>


                    <fieldset>

                        <table class="ui-accordion">
                        <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                    MachID</td>
                                <td align="left">
                              <%--   <div class="input-prepend" title="Select Country   Name">--%>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                         onselectedindexchanged="ddid_SelectedIndexChanged"> 

                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Empcode" runat="server" Text="EmpCode"></asp:Label>
                                <td align="left">


                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                 </td>

                            </tr>

                                <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                 <input type="radio" name="type" value="Fresher" />Fresher
                                 <input type="radio" name="type" value="Experienced" />Experienced
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                  Company</td>
                                <td align="left">
                                 <div class="input-prepend" title="Autogenerated District ID" data-rel="tooltip">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomp" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                  From Date</td>
                                <td align="left">
                                 <div class="input-prepend" title="Enter District Name" data-rel="tooltip">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfrom" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="Calendarextender1" TargetControlID ="txtfrom" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server"></ajax:CalendarExtender> 

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="style2">
                                  To Date</td>
                                <td align="left">
                                 <div class="input-prepend" title="Enter District Name" data-rel="tooltip">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtto" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="Calendarextender2" TargetControlID ="txtto" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server"></ajax:CalendarExtender> 

                                </td>
                            </tr>
      <tr>
                                <td class="style2">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    &nbsp; </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                  &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                                    Height="36px" Width="74px" onclick="Button1_Click" />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" class="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                                    Height="36px" Width="74px" PostBackUrl="~/districtDetails.aspx" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td class="style2">
                                     &nbsp;</td>
                                 <td align="left">
                                     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>


                        </fieldset>
                </form>

            </div><!--/span-->
        </div><!--/row-->
        </div>
  </div>

  </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have you checked JS errors in your console after refreshing ?

Comment: Tiki-Web, No how to check it? using break point??

Comment: for what is your `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel2" runat="server"></asp:UpdatePanel>` inside the first `UpdatePanel`, and what did you use your `UpdatePanel` for?

Comment: Kyojimaru, these update panels used for ajax(page refresh)

Comment: @Dwane what exactly did you refresh or change inside the `UpdatePanel`? Are there any element that `value` will be changed based on the selected option?

Comment: Kyojimaru, I didnt refreshed anything I just clicked on fresher radio button then txtboxes hide after that I selected dropdownlist then selected radiobutton got deselected and unable to hide text boxes also

Comment: @Dwane, have you tried to hide it before select from the `dropdownlist`, is it working in the first place? And where's the `dropdownlist` code

Comment: @Kyojimaru, Yes before select dropdownlist and before click on submit button it works fine. But after select dropdownlist or button click it wont work. I have uploaded my dropdown list code also

Comment: last one, are there any `value` that will be changed if you select one of the `list` in the `dropdown` menu?

Comment: @Kyojimaru, Yes underneath of dropdown list I have a text box  according to dropdown value the text box value will change.eg.if i selected machID 201 from dropdown then text box fill 201 id name from datbase)

Comment: @DwaneMarsh , have you tried with small letter `show()` , as this is the valid function, not `Show`?

Comment: @Arindam Nayak, Yes now I changed but again no changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using an `UpdatePanel`, it will refresh everything inside it's `<ContentTemplate>`, which in your case has `input[name="type"]` inside it.

Because it's refreshed, the `on('click', function() {` isn't binding the current `radiobutton` with the `name="type"` anymore, thus make the `click` never triggered after you select one item inside the `dropdown`, what you need is to wrap the `UpdatePanel` only for things that you want to be refreshed or changed only, like this for your case:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" class="style2">
                MachID
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                     onselectedindexchanged="ddid_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" class="style2">
                <asp:Label ID="Empcode" runat="server" Text="EmpCode"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Other Way**

Use the `jQuery on click selector`, you just need to change

```
$('input[name="type"]').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Experienced') {
        $('#txtcomp').show();
        $('#txtfrom').show();
        $('#txtto').show();
}
```

too

```
$('.ui-accordion').on('click', 'input[name="type"]', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Experienced') {
        $('#txtcomp').show();
        $('#txtfrom').show();
        $('#txtto').show();
}
```

Comment: NOw it works fine. But because of removed update panel, dropdown takes more time to refresh page and fill text box data

Comment: @Dwane, it works if you remove the `UpdatePanel` because it will do a full page reload which will recall the `on click function` again. If you need the page not to be seen as refreshed, you better stick with the `UpdatePanel`, but if it's ok if the user see the page being refreshed, it's ok to not use the `UpdatePanel`. And the time it takes to refresh the page when you use `UpdatePanel` should be the same or faster than not using it (depend on the ViewState in your page)

Answer (score 0):

The show function is k senstive. Try this:

```
$('#txtcomp,#txtfrom,#txtto').show();
```

Comment: The basic reason that you not able to show/hide after refreshing the page is "**$(...).Show is not a function**". Jquery doesn't know function name **Show**.

Comment: Sorry same issue again